# How to vertically align a <p> inside a <div>?

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario in front of me:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/

Here i have been trying to vertically align the `<p>` tag inside my `<div>`. I considered a number of solutions including `vertical-align`, mathematically calculating the `padding` for my `<p>` etc. None of these seem to be the ideal solution since my HTML will be auto-generated and the text inside the span would be variable.

I also spent quite some time searching for the solution on this portal but there seemed to be a consensus that without knowing the `height` of the content it is difficult to vertically align it. In my case the height of the content is not known but it is assurred that it will not be greater than the containing `<div>`.

Can anyone suggest me a way to find a solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

**single line**

For single lines making the line-height of your p equal to the height of your div is the easiest way.

```
<div style="background-color:#4F81BD; height: 88px; width: 148px; ">
    <p style="text-align:center; line-height: 88px">
        <span style="font-size:41px; color:#FFFFFF; ">One</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/2/

---

**multiple lines**

If you want it to work with more than one line you should make your div act as a table cell. Table cells allow vertical centering. This centering is called middle centering. In order to do so add:

```
display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle
```

To your div.

```
<div style="background-color:#4F81BD; height: 200px; width: 148px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">
    <p style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="font-size:41px; color:#FFFFFF; ">One Two Three</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/8/

More information about centering: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: what if the contents of the text get spanned to two or three lines? Like this: fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/7

Comment: if you use display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle the height doesn't matter. It will automatically vertical center.

Comment: @osi your solution works in the fiddle but unfortunately if the containing div has a `position:absolute;` property (which it does in my actual HTML) it doesn't works. Any work-around for this problem?

Comment: Then you should know the height. Otherwise it will be centered since the div will be as large as the content of the p, or do you mean the p is positioned absolute in the div?

Comment: @osi no, only the div is absolutely positioned. I am thinking of giving the <p> the same height as the div and using `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` in the <p>

Comment: Then this could be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7Z6BX/ But then you need to specify a size to your p.

Comment: Sorry but no, absolute values like these cannot be used by me since the text is not known to me. The text is auto-generated, I am only designing the HTML around the text.

Comment: If no height is known, then table cell is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

try with `line-height`:

```
<div style="background-color:#4F81BD; height: 88px; width: 148px; ">
    <p style="text-align:center; line-height:88px;">
        <span style="font-size:41px; color:#FFFFFF; ">One</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/4/)

Comment: what if the contents of the text get spanned to two or three lines? Like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/7/

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
div{

    position:relative
        vertical-align:middle;
}
p{

    position:absolute;
}
```

here a example:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/6/

Comment: I should mention that the containing div already has a `position:absolute;` property. I didn't mentioned because I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: no problem u can use position absolute for a container div also
http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/11/

Comment: But now it messes up the `text-align:center;`

Comment: No, didn't work. Plus my div has a property `position:absolute;` you gave it `position:relative;`

Comment: Oops sorry my mistake. But your solution wouldn't handle multiple lines of text.

Comment: i see,i think using table is only solution for you

Comment: Hmm.. well thanx anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
p{
    display:table;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
span{
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fr3TD/13/)